# superset connect to clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse, apache-superset

I already added 'clickhouse-connect>=0.4.1' to ./docker/requirements-local.txt
but it's failed when i connect to clickhouse.
it shows
(builtins.NoneType) None [SQL: Error executing HTTP request http://superset.typhur.cn:8123] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkGKl.png)

then i found it in clickhouse logs.
the method shows HTTP/1.0 Not GET/POST, and User-Agent is none,
it looks like not use the clickhouse-connect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYTDJ.png)

how to fix it?
thanks

i try to connect superset to clickhouse,
i expected it will be successful,
but it's failed

Comment: Hi -- I'm checking to see if clickhouse-connect builds and works correctly with the latest Superset version.  What superset version and clickhouse-connect version are you using?

Comment: Superset displays Version: 0.0.0-dev. i just used it for a week, maybe it's the latest version? The version of clickhouse-connect is 0.5.7. thanks

Comment: thanks -- I think you should be okay if you use a non-dev version of Superset, but we will get this fixed over the new few days.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error and it looks like you're using the correct port?  Is it possible your ClickHouse server is configured to use HTTPS using port 8443 instead?

Comment: Also does it work if you don't include the database in the SQL URI?

Comment: Just as an example, this works for me on current master (using my local clickhouse server):  `clickhousedb://geoff:password@localhost:8123/default`